# assigning a value within a char array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX40 40

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */


Int40 *parseString(char *str)
{
    Int40 *p;
    char *ptr;
    int i, len, value, ptrValue;

    printf("%s\n", str);


        for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == 'a')
    {
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);
            str[i] = '0';
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 // char string[40] = "
 // char *str = string;
    Int40 *p;


    parseString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567");

    return 0;
}
```

In my parseString function, between the two printf statements, I'm trying to assign the value at the specific point of 'a' to 0. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be attempting this, and I would like to keep the variables the same as well.

Comment: You're trying to modify a string constant. "Constant" means just that--you can't modify it.

Comment: Always compile with **warnings enabled**. That will point out a number of issues with your code, that the compiler can help you fix if you let it. @LeeDanielCrocker, you are correct, but the verbiage for the *"string constant"* is *"string-literal"* (but it was quite apparent what you meant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are passing to `parseString` a pointer to a
string literal. Modifying the contents of string literals is undefined behaviour
and most of the times string literals reside in read only memory, that's why
your program crashes.

You have to create an array and initialize it with the string you want, then
pass that array to the function:

```
#include <string.h>

void parseString(char *str, size_t len)
{
    printf("%s\n", str);


    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == 'a')
        {
            printf("%c\n", str[i]);
                str[i] = '0';
            printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char text[] = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567";

    parseString(text, sizeof text / sizeof *text);

    return 0;
}
```

Bear in mind when you pass an array to a function, the function gets only a
pointer to the first element of the array. For that reason the function being
called cannot determine the length of the array. It's better practice to pass
the length of the array as well. That's why I added `size_t len` as an argument
in `parseString`. In `main` where the `array` is declared, I calculate the
length of the array with `sizeof text / size *text`. Note that this only works
with pure array, if you did `sizeof str / sizeof *str` in `parseString`, you
will definitively get a wrong result, that's why you should always pass the
length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is having undefined behavior.

As per the standard attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior because they may be stored in read-only storage or combined with other string literals.

You are passing string literal to `parseString()` function:

```
parseString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567");
```

and in `parseString()`, trying to modify it:

```
str[i] = '0';
```

Instead, in `main()` function you can do:

```
char str[] = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567";
```

which is equivalent to:

```
char str[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','\0'};
```

*[Note the **terminating null-character** at the end.]*

So, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void parseString(char *pstr)
{
    char * str = pstr;
    printf("%s\n", str);
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == 'a')
        {
            printf("%c\n", str[i]);
            str[i] = '0';
            printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", pstr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    char str[] = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567";
    parseString(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in my program, I am only demonstrating the replacement of `'a'` with `'0'` character. Hence, I removed `typedef struct Int40...` which exists in OP's code.