# How to cast a string to a integer

Tags: c

I have a 40 digit hex number stored in a string, I have to store it inside a struct called Int40 that only contains a pointer to an int.

```
 typedef struct Int40    
 {    
    // a dynamically allocated array to hold a 40     
    // digit integer, stored in reverse order    
    int  *digits;    
} Int40;
```

this is what I have tried

```
Int40 *parseString(char *str)
{
    Int40 *value = malloc(sizeof(Int40) * MAX40);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX40; i++)
      {
         value[i] = (int)str[i];
      }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    Int40 *p;
    p = parseString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567");
    printf("-> %d\n", *p);
}
```

I know that an Int cant contain 40 digits thats why I tried to store each number from the string in an array of integers but my code doesnt seem to work.
Edit: Also the number contains letters because is a hex number, will I have to the get the ascii value of the hex number to be able to store it in the array of int, how do i do that?

Comment: Casting will not do that for you. You will have to parse the string.

Comment: also, you are trying to assign values to a struct rather than to a struct's member.  `INT40.digits` is never used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assigning a value within a char array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121452/assigning-a-value-within-a-char-array-pointer)

Comment: what do you mean with storing the string in an array of integers? what is supposed to be on each integer from the string.... as each integer (assuming 32bit word) supports for 8 hex digits, you can store your string in an array of five (or more) `int`s.  But, what do you want exactly to do?

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like the following (note that I omit verification of the argument `char*` and also assume that hex characters are lowercase)

```
// with if statements:

Int40 *parseString(char *str)
{
    Int40 *value = malloc(sizeof(Int40) * MAX40);
    // save the digits array locally (same memory address as value)
    int* digits = value->digits;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX40; i++)
    {
         char c = str[i];

         // decimal digits case
         if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
             digits[i] = c - '0'; // subtract '0' to get the numberical value of c 
         } else { // hex case
             digits[i] = (c - 'a') + 10; // subtract 'a' to get the numerical value of c as 0 + 10 for hex characters A - F
         }
    }
    return value;
}
```

An alternative:

```
// with a switch statements:

Int40 *parseString(char *str)
{
    Int40 *value = malloc(sizeof(Int40) * MAX40);
    // save the digits array locally (same memory address as value)
    int* digits = value->digits;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX40; i++)
    {
         char c = str[i];
         switch (c) {
         // hex 10 - 15
         case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': 
         case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
             digits[i] = (c - 'a') + 10;  
             break;
         // hex 0 - 9
         default:
             digits[i] = c - '0';
         }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int* hex;
hex parseString(char *str)
{
    hex value = (hex)malloc(sizeof(int)*40);
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
      {
         value[i] = str[i];
      }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    hex p;
    p = parseString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567");
    printf("-> %d\n", p[0]);
}
```

**...**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Int40 
{

    int* hex; 
}Int40;
Int40 parseString(char *str)
{
    Int40 value;
    value.hex = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*40);
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
      {
         value.hex[i] = str[i];
      }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    Int40 p;
    p = parseString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567");
    printf("-> %d\n", p.hex[0]);
}
```